# Create custom circular progress indicator in flutter with custom stroke cap

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-canvas, flutter-circularprogressindicator

I need to create this percent indicator[image]

How can i achieve this? I've tried percent_indicator package in Flutter, but the main problem is that we have a limited amount of strokeCap options. I've also tried to do that with two arcs, but the problem remains the same. Is there is a way to create a custom strokeCap, or maybe another way without canvas.drawArc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve this using a CustomPainter. Below is my solution.

> **NOTE**
> You can pass in a dynamic value to update the progress bar's value. I have not done that since it should be trivial to implement once the rendering is correct ;). You might also update the colors to fit your need!

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart' as vmath;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: TestPage(),
    );
  }
}

class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: MyPainter(),
            child: Container(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // Get the center of the canvas 
    final center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
    
    // Draw the gray background seen on the progress indicator
    // This will act as the background layer.
    canvas.drawCircle(
      center,
      85,
      Paint()
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..color = Colors.black12
        ..strokeWidth = 30,
    );

    // Create a new layer where we will be painting the 
    // actual progress indicator
    canvas.saveLayer(
      Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: 200, height: 200),
      Paint(),
    );

    // Draw the light green portion of the progress indicator
    canvas.drawArc(
      Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: 170, height: 170),
      vmath.radians(0),
      vmath.radians(200),
      false,
      Paint()
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
        ..color = Colors.green[100]
        ..strokeWidth = 30,
    );

    // Draw the dark green portion of the progress indicator
    // Basically, this covers the entire progress indicator circle.
    // But because we have set the blending mode to srouce-in (BlendMode.srcIn), 
    // only the segment that is overlapping with the lighter portion will be visible.
    canvas.drawArc(
      Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: 155, height: 155),
      vmath.radians(0),
      vmath.radians(360),
      false,
      Paint()
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
        ..color = Colors.green
        ..strokeWidth = 15
        ..blendMode = BlendMode.srcIn,
    );
    // we fatten the layer
    canvas.restore();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

You should get an output that looks like the below:
[image]

Comment: anytime ;) I'm glad it helped

Comment: Can you please add comments to your MyPainter class? I'm new to Flutter, finding it hard to understand. @YounssAITMOU

Comment: I have added a few comments that could help understand the code. If you need specific help, please, let me know what's not clear and I will be happy to clarify ;)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else, this package seems to propose exactly this kind of indicator widget: [syncfusion_flutter_gauges](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_gauges)