# Is there a way to create this custom progress bar with docked action button in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-animation, flutter-circularprogressindicator

I am trying to replicate the below image but I'm having a hard time doing so. I tried to use `sleek_circular_slider`, but it wasn't giving me what I wanted. Any help is much appreciated

Reference image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one Custom progress bar implementation. Have a look at the answer.

[Create custom circular progress indicator in flutter with custom stroke cap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67336319/create-custom-circular-progress-indicator-in-flutter-with-custom-stroke-cap)

Comment: Thank you for the help. How about the button to be docked. I have gone through the thread but the button is the most important.

Answer (score 0):

i think use of Positioned Widget can help to set Progress bar at dock

```
new Positioned(
       left: 30.0,
       top: 30.0,
       child: new Container(
         width: 100.0,
         height: 80.0,
         decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
         child: new Text('hello'),
        )
      ),
```

[And this will help to create round circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67336319/create-custom-circular-progress-indicator-in-flutter-with-custom-stroke-cap)

Comment: I had solved the positioning of the button. My main issue was then to make the circle wobbly like in the image. I had seen the stackoverflow thread you sent and it creates a circular progress bar. My main aim was to make it wobbly.